# Bind DropDownList to decimal number

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I have a DropDownList inside EditItemTemplate of a FormView that it is bound to a data field with *real* data type.

```
<asp:FormView ...>
    ...
    <EditItemTemplate>
        ...
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlKidPriceScale" runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("KidPriceScale") %>'>
            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="0">Free</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="0.5">Half Price</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        ....
    </EditItemTemplate>
    ....
</asp:FormView>
```

When I choose "Half Price" option ("0.5" value) from DropDownlist and press update button, I will get this error:

```
Input string was not in a correct format
```

But the "Free" Option is fine.

And When I set 0.5 value directly in database, I will get this error when editig record:

```
ddlKidPriceScale' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items
```

I tried these in binding context too:

```
SelectedValue='<%# Bind("KidPriceScale2","{0:g}") %>'
```

And

```
SelectedValue='<%# Bind("KidPriceScale2","{0:f}") %>'
```

And

```
SelectedValue='<%# Bind("KidPriceScale2","{0:n}") %>'
```

I'm real confused!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the cause!

My `CurrentCulture` was `'fa-IR'`. In this culture, DecimalSeperator is `/` not `.`

After adding this Code, problem fixed:

```
protected void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
    }
```